# Do Android version code constants work with older versions?

Tags: android, versioning

Can I use Android version code constants with older Android runtimes? For instance,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
   android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) ...
```

would this run without crash on old devices running Android operating system before HONEYCOMB when this constant has been first defined? Assuming we compile it with recent enough SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this will work.

The reason for this is that `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` is an `int`. `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` is just an alias (the `int` equals `11`) for `11`, as can be seen in an IDE such as Eclipse:

```
int android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB = 11 [0xb]
```

So this will work as it'll just check if the `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is greater than or equal to 11.

Comment: How does it get translated to an int at compile time? I just read Java does not have support for aliases.

Comment: @FD_ Looking closer, it actually *is* an `int`. I'd assume it's some sort of Android variable that is packaged with the APK or something.

Comment: Ok, I had hoped to learn a bit more on how it actually works.

Comment: `int` alone is not sufficient. `static final int` allows the compiler to inline the value at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. It works because the `int` values are `static final`. The compiler will inline them into the bytecode at compile time. No symbol import is required at runtime.