# Why do android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES work on older platforms

Tags: android, version, adt

As pointed out by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837356/do-android-version-code-constants-work-with-older-versions/21837443) and a bit of testing I did, `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES` work on platform versions that are older than the platform version of the `VERSION_CODE` you are using.

E.g. this:

```
android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
```

Also works on Gingerbread devices, although Honecomb was released *after* Gingerbread.

This seems to only work if your target SDK is later than the VERSION_CODE you use, which leads me to the assumtion that the version code somehow get compiled into the APK from the target SDK.

Now, my question is:

How does that work? According to the accepted answer of the linked question, this works via an int alias, but Java does not seem to have support for aliases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a compile-time constant that gets inlined in the generated bytecode. Because of that, the symbol does not need to be resolved at runtime.

A compile-time constant is something that is

- declared `final`
- primitive or `String`
- initialized within declaration
- initialized with a [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

Comment: Thanks! The thing I forgot was that final ints get replaced at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

The `VERSION_CODES` are all static final ints, meaning that when you build your app, all of the variables are just replaced with numbers. Basically, if you look in your app's bytecode after compilation, you will likely see any references to the `VERSION_CODES` just replaced with the actual `int` that each version code variable represents.