# How do application know android.os.Build infomation

Tags: android, build, version

We can get Build infomation such as VERSION.SKD_INT by android.os.Build. But all of them are `static final` like [Build.VERSION#SDK_INT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION#SDK_INT). If I understand correctly, that means these value will be decided in the complie time. My question is how do they change on different devices even if it's the same apk?

Take SDK_INT for example, we can [check version code constants work with older versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837356/do-android-version-code-constants-work-with-older-versions). That means `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU` is decided in the compile time. How wasn't `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` decided in complie time?

```java
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
   android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the `android.os.Build` class, you will see that it comes from the `android.jar` library.

This library, as you're seeing it from Android Studio, only contains stubs and won't be embedded within your app.

At runtime, your application will use the `android.jar` that is present on your device and the `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` property will effectively be set to represent your current OS version.